# Copying data from one array to another causes the result array to consists only of repeating entries of the last item from the input array

Tags: arrays, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to write an async function that creates a new array of type MusicWithMetadata from  an array of type Music. I've tested it with 6 entries in the input array. For some reason, the result array consists just of 6 entries of the last item from the input array.

```
private async getMusicWithMetadata(music: Music): Promise<MusicWithMetadata> {
    const metadata = await musicMedatada.parseFile(music.src);
    const musicWithMetadata = NullMusicWithMetadata;
    musicWithMetadata.id = music.id;
    musicWithMetadata.src = music.src;
    musicWithMetadata.src_type = music.src_type;
    musicWithMetadata.title =
      metadata.common.title !== undefined
        ? metadata.common.title
        : this.getFileNameWithoutExtension(music.src);
    musicWithMetadata.artists = metadata.common.artists;
    musicWithMetadata.album = metadata.common.album;
    musicWithMetadata.albumArt =
      metadata.common.picture !== undefined
        ? `data:${
            metadata.common.picture[0].format
          };base64,${metadata.common.picture[0].data.toString('base64')}`
        : metadata.common.picture;
    return musicWithMetadata;
  }

 private async getMusicArrayWithMetadata(musicList: Array<Music>) {
    const test1 = musicList.map(async (music) => {
      const musicWithMetadata = await this.getMusicWithMetadata(music);
      return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log(musicWithMetadata);
        return musicWithMetadata;
      });
    });

    await Promise.all(test1).then((music) => {
      console.log(music);
    });
  }
```

Here I call the method.

```
 public async queueAll() {
    const musicList = await this.musicRepository.getAll();
    MusicManager.queue = await this.getMusicArrayWithMetadata(musicList);
    MusicManager.currentlyPlayingPosition = 0;
  }
```

Input:
[image]
Actual Output:
[image]
Desired Output:
The result array should contain all 6 items from the input array.

Comment: could you give an example of input, desired output and the output you are getting?

Comment: @WilsonPena I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: how are you calling this method?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` on the map, because it returns an array of promises, also you need to return the resulting array:

```
private async getMusicWithMetadata(music: Music): Promise<MusicWithMetadata> {
    const metadata = await musicMedatada.parseFile(music.src);
    return {
      ...music,
      title: metadata.common.title !== undefined
        ? metadata.common.title
        : this.getFileNameWithoutExtension(music.src),
      artists: metadata.common.artists,
      album: metadata.common.album,
      albumArt: metadata.common.picture !== undefined
        ? `data:${
            metadata.common.picture[0].format
          };base64,${metadata.common.picture[0].data.toString('base64')}`
        : metadata.common.picture,
    };
  }

  private async getMusicArrayWithMetadata(musicList: Array<Music>) {
    const test1 = await Promise.all(musicList.map(async (music) => {
      const musicWithMetadata = await getMusicWithMetadata(music);
      console.log(musicWithMetadata);
      return musicWithMetadata;
    }));
    return test1;
  }
```

I refactored the `getMusicWithMetadata` but what you really need is the changes in the `getMusicArrayWithMetadata` function.

**UPDATE**

also you should put the return type `: Promise<MusicWithMetadata[]>` on the last method:

```
private async getMusicArrayWithMetadata(musicList: Array<Music>): Promise<MusicWithMetadata[]>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working great. I'm new to promises and still learning how they work.

Comment: sure, I'm glad if I helped!